# 24 Hour time format in Angular Material Input Component

Tags: angular-material

I have an Input of `type='time'` from `Angular Material` and I want to use it with 24-hour format. I can't find how to do that.

```
   <md-input-container class="input-material-element">
          <input mdInput type="time" placeholder="{{labels.TIME_OF_DEPARTURE}}" [(ngModel)]="model.departureTime">
   </md-input-container>
```

Answer (score 5):

`Angular Material` does not format the `<input type="time">`.

That's the browsers implementation / presentation of the HTML5 `<input>` elements of type `time`. In some browsers you will get the desired 24-hour format and in some you get 12 hour with AM/PM.

You want to take a look at the documentation to make the appropriate business decision for your use case. Safari for example does not yet support time `input` natively, while on mobile platforms some browsers even tend to have nice user interfaces for the `time` input type.

[mdn web docs HTML/Element/input/time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time)